# How to override constructor definitions of browser APIs in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I want to override the constructor of a new browser API which is still experimental. The default `lib.dom.ts` for this API has the constructor definition which I want to override. How should I go about this?

I have extracted out what I'm trying to do in the REPL [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/PTAEBsEsCMDoBMD2BbWAXAzqAUPApgMbgCGATnqAG5mgDCAyo2gJ7h70AWeeaAXKAG9soEaAAOpRGinMxefgyat2XHgG5hogHZ4A7gAoAlAsb0WbTtzQaAvhuwhQAc3CJoxcBgToMuQiXIqGkUzZUsefiERHQNILUg+QVA0BLZ+DDRSOKdQG2M6U3MVK1t7R1pEfGwCRC0M0CwAXlAYgqULVTR9KOTU+VAAcmRmAFoM5QxOgew8tSA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare this type in `Window` interface and run it from `window.` global object.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/PTAEBsEsCMDoBMD2BbWAXAzqAUPApgMbgCGATnqAG5mgDCAyo2gJ7h70AWeeaAXKAG9soUADs8AdwAUZAOb9io5gEp+DJq3ZceAbmGgCiURjSkArgTSJSM0vNCKVaxvRZtO3NHoC+e7NkhRNDxSADNiAgoAdUCkCUF9dVdNDx5+IRFxaTkFJVU6FzctTz0RQ2NTCysbHIc85w13bS9sX1b-EDpEfGxyk1AsAF4xSVAJWMQJWCSi1LQpDNA0SDQ2fgByZGYAWhNNDGb11uUdIA)